# iOS App crashing with low memory warning in table view with custom web view cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, didreceivememorywarning

As per requirement I am suppose to show table with custom web view cells. User can add manually cells to table. Up to some extent it works fine but when user keeps on adding cells counting more than 15, controller class gets low memory warning & app crashes.

In actual there are couple of more parameters on UI.While drilling down with this issue I identified this is causing due to multiple Web View's. Web view is used to show/edit text with different styles & colors.

Appreciate any pointers to get rid of this issue.

Comment: Show some code, specifically the contents of your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You are probably not reusing the off-screen cells in the right way.

Comment: Are you reusing your cells?

Comment: Yes, i am reusing cells.I have 5 sections which have different custom cells. I think problem is, each custom cell contains web view which accumulating memory.

Comment: How did you declare...     @property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView                 *forwebView;     you declare as property and check.

Comment: @Jaleel : yes I have declared property with "strong"- ARC

Comment: @Learner You tried as "retain". it may work...